# How can I track the real time/date of an incident against response time if it is different to issue creation date/time on JIRA Service Desk

Tags: jira

I want to track SLAs (like time to first response and time to resolution) but my service team may receive requests via phone in some situations where the request cannot be logged to the JIRA Service Desk system immediately. I want to either change the date/time that the issue is created to reflect when the incident was truly discovered OR have separate custom fields to track this and use these to measure SLAs.

Is there:

a) any way to create an issue and then change the creation date (to the real discovery date/time - not ideal)?

or b) use a custom field, e.g. detection date/time to track start time and another field, e.g. response time, to end the SLA. And then track the SLA's using these fields.

or c) use a custom field, e.g. detection date/time to track start time and another field, e.g. response date/time - when the incident was responded to if different to when the response was logged on JIRA, and create a third field that will be auto-populated when the user logs a date/time in the response date/time field - which reflects the response time SLA.

Answer (score 0):

Service Desk SLA works independently, You cannot set custom fields that time will be taken from and included in SLA calculations.

**a)** You can change creation date, this example shows You how [How to change issue creation date](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-change-the-issue-creation-date-using-a-database-update-334430256.html). But in Your case I would write a plugin that will set creation date with REST in database (Dangerous but I got 3 plugins digging and changing things in DB and for now nothing wrong happened) and reindex issue after it.

**b)** Impossible, Jira SD SLA does not allow using Your custom fields to calculate time.

**c)** It would be alternative to SLA and if You have Jira Script Runner You can write simple Groovy script to calculate it or simple Jira Plugin.

In my opinion best solution for You is to write Your own plugin where You will have 3 custom fields

1. Real creation date [Date]
2. Response time [Date]
3. Calculated time (best would be Your own custom field to show it in friendly way)

Plugin will be triggered when Response Time field will be filled or if user fill it on transition then You may include Your plugin as postfunction that will calculate it.